# Not able to write value to a specific characteristic using Bleak Python

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm trying to write a byte array to a characteristic using Bleak but it just not writing and get stuck the that point. I checked the service and it's specific characteristic to which I'm able successfully write from nRF connect app.

Service of a characteristic: **C0B0A000-18EB-499D-B266-2F2910744274** 
It's characteristic: **C0B0A001-18EB-499D-B266-2F2910744274** 
**Line of code with issue**: `await client.write_gatt_char(characteristic, data=data, response=True)`

Python code:

```py
async def write_characteristics(address: str, data: bytearray, service_uuid: str, characteristic_uuid: str):
    async with BleakClient(address, timeout=20) as client:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        try:
            log.info(f"Connected to {address}")
            # get selected service using uuid
            svc = client.services.get_service(service_uuid)
            # get defined characteristic from a selected service using characteristic uuid
            characteristic = svc.get_characteristic(characteristic_uuid)
            # write to the selected characteristic using uuid
            log.info(f"Writing to {characteristic.uuid}")
            await client.write_gatt_char(characteristic, data=data, response=True) # here my code get stuck
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            loop.stop()
            loop.close()
```

**Screenshot**: nRF connect screenshot for the same service and characteristic 
[image]

Can someone tell me where I'm doing wrong? As per the idea from nRF connect, it should be working

Comment: In the nRF connect app what does it say are the properties of that characteristic?  Is it `write` or `write no response`?

Comment: It's [notify, read, write]

Comment: nRF is reporting that it got a notification. You don't seem to have done [start_notify](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/client.html?highlight=write_gatt_char#bleak.BleakClient.start_notify) on the Bleak Client.

Comment: Do you think it's compulsory to use **start_notify**?

Comment: Without knowing the details of your device and this service it is difficult to speak in definite terms. The main purpose of `start_notify` is to register a callback to handle the response from the peripheral. The characteristic says it supports `Notify` so I don't know how else you would get the response from the peripheral.

Comment: Actually, I don't need response at all. I just need to write it but even that's not happening. I'm doing all these stuff on my Cowboy C4 E-bike.